# Why are the charts in this set all $C^\infty$-related?

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm reading the first volume of Spivak's differential geometry series, and am having a tough time convincing myself of something mentioned in the proof of Lemma 1, Chapter 2.

Let $M$ be an $n$-manifold, let $A$ be an atlas of $C^\infty$-related charts on $M$, and let $A'$ be the set of all charts which are $C^\infty$-related to each chart in $A$. **Supposedly, all charts in $A'$ are $C^\infty$-related.**

Now, any two charts $x,y \in A'$ are clearly $C^\infty$-related (by assumption) if either $x$ or $y$ belongs to $A$. But if $x,y \in A'-A$, I am completely lost as to why $x$ and $y$ should be $C^\infty$-related (especially since being $C^\infty$-related is not a transitive relation).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try picking a neighborhood of a point and using the charts from A.

Comment: $C^\infty$ related is a trasitive relation.

Comment: @Gil Bor: No it isn't. For a counterexample, check out Jason Devito's answer at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110576/is-c-infty-related-an-equivalence-relation